# React returns errors ONLY when saving context but when I reload everything is normal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create this web app with a context that contains two functions. Then I pass these functions to two components and everything works fine. I can use the functions, I get no errors when using the app, no errors when I reload. BUT when I save the context file -that is, I ctrl+S on my vsCode context.jsx file- , the app crashes and I get undefined errors for the two functions Im passing. If I reload the webpage it all goes back to normal. Anyone experienced this? I'm not looking to solve my code I just want to know: Is it ok for a react app to crash when saving individual files as long as the app works fine when launched?

Comment: Not enough data. Provide some your codes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Getting this error too.  No edits to context file are needed, just hit save, and other components using this context get null, and my object destructuring throws